# How do I add or manipulate Application/System Indicators in the login screen?

Tags: indicator, login-screen

I would like to remove several of the Indicators that usually appear in the upper-right-hand side of the login screen.  In particular, I would like to remove the accessibility, keyboard layout, power, and sound indicators, although it would be nice to know how to generically add or remove indicators.  How can I do this?

Comment: You are using Unity-greeter? There should be a config file in `/etc/lightdm/`, but I don't remember which one and can't check as I am sitting on a Windows machine at the moment. Read all files - At least one should contain a section about the indicators you mentioned. Copy the file as backup and find out how to edit it. Or post its content (as edit to your question!) and I will have a look. You have to leave me a comment (@ByteCommander) then...

Comment: What's the system you're using ? 14.04 ?

Comment: @Serg, yes, I'm using 14.04.

Comment: @ByteCommander, there are four greeter configuration files in my `/etc/lightdm`: `lightdm.conf`, `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`, `lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf`, and `lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf`.  I have no idea what the difference between any of them is, but I did try to disable the login screen clock through each of them, and it didn't work.

Comment: I am on 15.04 now and am afraid that I seem to have none of these config files any more... Could you upload your four config files (to http://pastebin.com/ for example) and share the link? I could look over them and see if they look about as I remember mine.

Comment: @ByteCommander, here are (most of the) files: http://pastebin.com/zZ6KjPNR

Comment: In file `lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` the line `show-indicators=~host;~spacer;~a11y;~session;~language;~a11y;~clock;~power;` should be responsible for which indicators are displayed. You could try and remove items from that list and see which indicators will disappear. I mean "clock" is clear, but no idea what e.g. "a11y" stands for... Doing a bit more researching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coming with different approach:

```
$ pstree
init─┬─...
     ├─lightdm─┬─Xorg
     │         ├─lightdm─┬─lightdm-greeter───unity-greeter───4*[{unity-greeter}]
     ...

$ dpkg -L unity-greeter
...
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml
...

$ more /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml

...
    <key name="indicators" type="as">
      <default>['ug-accessibility', 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.session', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.
power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application']</default>
      <summary>Which indicators to load</summary>
    </key>
...
```

`unity-greeter` is run by `lightdm` user! Instead of looking around for a way to change the `dconf` setting for that ghost user. I override the default. Tested in Ubuntu 14.04 64bit (VirtualBox).

1. Create new `dconf` override file

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/90_unity-greeter.gschema.override
   ```

   Put these two lines in it with indicator you want to keep:

   ```
   [com.canonical.unity-greeter]
   indicators=['com.canonical.indicator.session']
   ```

   Default is:

   ```
   ['ug-accessibility', 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.session', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application']
   ```
2. Recompile `glib` schemas

   ```
   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   ```
3. Restart the display manager

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

Comment: This one allows me to remove the accessibility (ug-accessibility) and wireless (application) indicators.  Between this answer and your previous one, it is now possible to remove every one of the preinstalled indicators.

Comment: @InkBlend, Actually this covers all indicators with single setting point. No need for [my other partial solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604564/how-do-i-add-or-manipulate-application-system-indicators-in-the-login-screen/622907#622907)

Answer (score 8):

One way that I have tried in Ubuntu 14.04 using LightDM (Default); Using Some config files stored in `/usr/share/unity/indicators/`

Let's say you want to hide keyboard indicator:

1. Open corresponding file for editing

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/unity/indicators/com.canonical.indicator.keyboard
   ```
2. Comment object paths for the mode you want to hide in, example this will hide it in the greeting screen and lock screen

   ```
   [Indicator Service]
   Name=indicator-keyboard
   ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/keyboard
   Position=80

   [desktop]
   ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/desktop

   #[desktop_greeter]
   #ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/desktop_greeter

   #[desktop_lockscreen]
   #ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/desktop_lockscreen

   [ubiquity]
   ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/keyboard/desktop
   ```
3. Reboot or just restart display manager

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

Comment: Aaa!  This is the first thing that I've tried that works!  However, I don't see either the wireless or the accessibility indicators present, both of which I want to hide.  Would you happen to know where these are?

Comment: I confirm that, network indicator which is created by `nm-applet` and I'm not sure about accessibility indicator.